# A math sequence, but also a English sequence!

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

What are the numbers in the question marks?

0, 1, 2, ?, 5, 6, 8, ?, 40, 46, 60, ?, 84

Answer (score 1):

I have a theory that

> These are numbers that, spelled out in English, have no duplicate letters.

This way

> The first question mark would be FOUR (since THREE has 2 E's), the second one - TEN (NINE, ELEVEN, TWELVE, *TEEN, TWENTY * and THIRTY * are out).

But I'm confused by the 3rd question mark, as

> There are multiple numbers between 60 and 84 that can be spelled without duplicate letters: SIXTY ONE, SIXTY FOUR and EIGHTY itself. I'm not sure how to pick just one of them...

Comment: Yeah, I found this pattern after searching it up on the OEIS, also with both 61 and 64 being between 60 and 84. I would take a random guess that the question asker accidentally wrote SIXTY as SIXETY, and 64 would be the correct answer, but that could be wrong.